# Assigning a Boolean value to a variable after using $.ajax()

Tags: ajax

I have written this Javascript code to validate my email address on a signup form; but after using $.ajax(), the returned value of the function is not correct (I suppose the returned value equal to 'false' but it would be 'true' if ajax success routine is executed)!! Can you give me a hand, please?

```
function validate_email(valID,displayID)
{
var email_format = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
var email = valID.val();
var return_status = true;

if(email == "")
{
        displayID.append('\u26A0'+' ');
        displayID.append('msg1');
        return_status = false;
} 
else if(!email_format.test(email))
{
        displayID.append('\u26A0'+' ');
        displayID.append('msg2');
        return_status = false;
}
else
{
    //Checks for email uniquness in the DB
    var str_temp=valID.val().toLowerCase();
    var data="email="+str_temp.trim();

    $.ajax({                                      
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php_routines/ajax_email_validator.php',   
        data: data,                  
        success: function(results)          
        {
            if (results==1)
            {
                displayID.append('\u26A0');
                displayID.append('msg3');
                return_status = false;                          
            }
        }
    });
}
return return_status;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is an async request.

What seems to happen is that you're returning *return_status* before your *$.ajax* finishes his tasks.

You should use promises to fix that or use a callback.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you guide me exactly what to do, please? I tried to use 'return' statements in 'if else if else' body but the result was not correct like before.

Comment: I used 'async: false' in $.ajax() and the problem solved. Thanks for the answer.